# Is there a function to calculate datediff in years, months and days in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

On redshift, I would like to display datediff in the form of years, months and days

I tried to use datediff and dateformat similar to postgre but does not work.

select date_format(date_diff('days','2019-01-01',current_date),'%y yr %c mth %e dy')

I expect above sql result in 2 years, 4 months, 26 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has a function called AGE() but it is not supported on Redshift. I created a Redshift version using a SQL UDF for this answer: [Netezza In-Built AGE function as UDF in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491128/netezza-in-built-age-function-as-udf-in-redshift/52598326#52598326)

```
/*
    Postgres AGE() Function
*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_postgres_age(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(64) 
STABLE AS $$
-- Input: '1994-04-04 20:10:52', '2018-09-24 11:31:05' -- Output: 24 years 5 mons 19 days 15:20:13
-- Input: '1994-10-04 20:10:52', '2019-06-12 11:31:05' -- Output: 24 years 8 mons 7 days 15:20:13
-- Check: SELECT '1994-10-04 20:10:52'::TIMESTAMP 
--               + INTERVAL '24 years' + INTERVAL '8 months' + INTERVAL '7 days'
--               + INTERVAL '15 hours' + INTERVAL '20 minutes' + INTERVAL '13 seconds';
-- =>     2019-06-12 11:31:05
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DATE_TRUNC('year', $1)
                              , DATE_TRUNC('year', CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, $1) > DATEPART(month, $2)
                                                        THEN $2 - INTERVAL '1 Year' ELSE $2 END)) > 0
            THEN DATEDIFF(year, DATE_TRUNC('year', $1)
                              , DATE_TRUNC('year', CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, $1) > DATEPART(month, $2)
                                                        THEN $2 - INTERVAL '1 Year' ELSE $2 END)) || ' years '
       ELSE '' END
    || CASE WHEN ABS(  DATEDIFF(month, DATE_TRUNC('month', $1), DATE_TRUNC('month', $2))
                     - DATEDIFF(month, DATE_TRUNC('year', $1)
                                     , DATE_TRUNC('year', CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, $1) > DATEPART(month, $2)
                                                               THEN $2 - INTERVAL '1 Year' ELSE $2 END))) > 0
            THEN DATEDIFF(month, DATE_TRUNC('month', $1), DATE_TRUNC('month', $2))
               - DATEDIFF(month, DATE_TRUNC('year', $1)
                               , DATE_TRUNC('year', CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, $1) > DATEPART(month, $2)
                                                         THEN $2 - INTERVAL '1 Year' ELSE $2 END)) || ' mons '
       ELSE '' END
    || CASE WHEN ABS( DATEDIFF(day, DATE_TRUNC('day', $1)+1, DATE_TRUNC('day', $2)) 
                    - DATEDIFF(day, DATE_TRUNC('month', $1), DATE_TRUNC('month', $2))) > 0
            THEN DATEDIFF(day, DATE_TRUNC('day', $1)+1, DATE_TRUNC('day', $2))
               - DATEDIFF(day, DATE_TRUNC('month', $1), DATE_TRUNC('month', $2)) || ' days '
       ELSE '' END
    || TO_CHAR((TIMESTAMP 'epoch' 
                + ( DATEDIFF(second, $1, DATE_TRUNC('day', $1)+1 )
                  + DATEDIFF(second, DATE_TRUNC('day', $2), $2) )
                * INTERVAL '1 Second '),'HH24:MI:SS') age
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
;
```

Comment: There is a bug, if the 1st parameter's month is greater than 2nd it doesn't return month part  `SELECT f_postgres_age('1994-10-04', '2019-06-12')` gives `25 years 7 days 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Date functions are different in Amazon Redshift.

See: [Date and Time Functions - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html)

I couldn't see a function to convert an interval (or number of days) into a human-friendly description. You could code it manually using several `DATE_PART()` commands.

Or, you could write a **Python UDF** that accepts the number of days and then formats it into a friendly string.